# php function with variable and array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to create a PHP function with 2 parameters. One parameter is a variable and the second is an array like this

```
<?php
function Myfunction($variable, $array=array()){
foreach($array as $item){
        echo $variable;
        echo  $item;
    }
}
?>
```

I want a call like this:

```
<?php
Myfunction(blue, 1,3,6,10,5);
?>
```

"blue" is the variable
"numbers" insert in an array.

I tried something but it does not work.

Who can help me with this?

Comment: Maybe this `Myfunction('blue', array(1,3,6,10,5));` will help.

Comment: Simple, just call it like this `MyFunction(blue, [1,3,6,10,5]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two possibilities:

You can wrap your values in an array (ie: `[]`), which I believe is what you intended:

```
Myfunction(blue, [1,3,6,10,5]);
```

Or you could take advantage of PHP's [variable argument list](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) and have your function parameters listed like so:

```
Myfunction($variable, ...$array);
```

Note the `...` before `$array`, this signifies that this parameter will accept a variable number of arguments. Keep in mind that parameter using `...` must be the last parameter in your argument list.
With this, you may call your function like so:

```
Myfunction(blue, 1,3,6,10,5);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Miroslav for the solution! I made the function with the advanced option :)